# How to change label values in Prometheus?

Tags: prometheus, promql

I can't execute PromQL query for change some of my label values.

I have some metric:

```
test_gauge{name="name_value",test_label="qwerty"} 12
```

And I want rename all of inserted values `name_value` and `qwerty` earlier for example in `renamed_value` and `renamed_qwerty` to make:

```
test_gauge{name="renamed_value",test_label="renamed_qwerty"} 12
```

Is this possible for Prometheus time-series database?

I didn't find any information about this. I found only how to rename label itself, but I need to change value of the label, not its name.

Answer (score 0):

To change values of the labels you can use same function as to renaming labels: [`label_replace`](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/querying/functions/#label_replace). For it to change value of the label you need to pass same name into destination and target labels.

For your example query will look like this

```
label_replace(
  label_replace(
    test_gauge{},
    "name","renamed_value",
    "name","name_value")
  "test_label","renamed_$1",
  "test_label","(.+)")
```

Here `label_replace` is applied tow times: one for each label.

Also notice, that here I showed two different approaches:

1. simple replacement of a single value with another value for `name`. Any metric `test_gauge` with label `name` set `name_value` will have it replaced with `renamed_value`. But other values of label `name` wouldn't be changed,
2. addition of the `renamed_` to **all** values of label `test_label`. Any value of `test_label` will be modified.

Additionally information:

- please notice, that last parameter for `label_replace` is a regex, and thus you might need to escape symbols with special meaning in regex before use. For example `a[b]` -> `a\\[b\\]`. Notice that escapement is done with two backslashes.
- remember that results of your modifications should result in unique labels sets. For example, you cannot replace label values to same value for all metrics, if that label is the only one for the metric.

You can find a couple demos demonstrating how it works [here](https://prometheus.demo.do.prometheus.io/graph?g0.expr=up%20%0A%23Original%20values%20of%20the%20metric&g0.tab=1&g0.stacked=0&g0.range_input=1h&g1.expr=label_replace(up%2C%22job%22%2C%22new_%241%22%2C%20%22job%22%2C%20%22(.%2B)%22)%20%0A%23Added%20%60new_%60%20in%20the%20beggining%20of%20all%20job%20labels&g1.tab=1&g1.stacked=0&g1.range_input=1h&g2.expr=label_replace(up%2C%22job%22%2C%22something%20else%22%2C%20%22job%22%2C%20%22alertmanager%22)%20%0A%23Replaced%20job%20label%20alertmanager%20with%20something%20else&g2.tab=1&g2.stacked=0&g2.range_input=1h&g3.expr=node_uname_info%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%23Original%20value%0Aor%20label_replace(node_uname_info%20%2C%22domainname%22%2C%22%241%22%2C%20%22domainname%22%2C%20%22%5C%5C((.%2B)%5C%5C)%22)%20%20%20%20%20%23Removed%20brackets%20from%20domaniname&g3.tab=1&g3.stacked=0&g3.range_input=1h&g4.expr=up%7Bjob%3D%22random%22%7D&g4.tab=1&g4.stacked=0&g4.range_input=1h&g5.expr=label_replace(up%7Bjob%3D%22random%22%7D%2C%22instance%22%2C%22something%20else%22%2C%20%22instance%22%2C%20%22.%2B%22)%20%0A%23This%20results%20in%20an%20error%20because%20all%20results%20have%20same%20labels%20set%20after%20this%20operation&g5.tab=1&g5.stacked=0&g5.range_input=1h).

Comment: Thanks for answer. I checked how it works. Perhaps I don't understand mechanics of db correctly? Your solution allows replace results in query response, but old names still in db. I can also get old name if I execute `test_gauge{}` query. I need to replace about 100 values, and hence there will be very long query string, even using RegEx. Is it possible to replace names so that I can then query `test_gauge{}` and get response with new names?

Comment: @manils, yes, this only changes label values in returned dataset. Stored values are kept the same. But why do you want to change  label values on the prometheus' side? It will be easier to change them in you code before exposing, IMO.

Comment: I would like to know if Prometheus has such an opportunity. Renaming in db will be best way to correct names without changing queries. The specific complexity lies in the number of queries being modified and the number of values being modified for this queries. In my opinion, a complex query string is worse than directly correcting an names in the database.

For the example, I will need to change 20 queries that will rename 100 names. This will make the queries very difficult to understand for subsequent developments. I would like to change the name in the database and not edit queries.

Comment: @manils, no, I mean why not to change your python code that exposes this metrics? Prometheus has an ability to change labels right after scraping: relabel_config. But question about it would be oftopic for SO, since it's configuration. But it will be ontopic at [Devops.se] or [su]